# LiquiBase & Spring boot - missing sequence

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, liquibase

In liquibase my changeset looks as below:

```
    <createSequence schemaName="public"
                    incrementBy="1"
                    minValue="1"
                    sequenceName="user_seq" />

    <createTable tableName="user" schemaName="public">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" defaultValueSequenceNext="user_seq">
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
```

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @SequenceGenerator(name="USER_SEQ",sequenceName="USER_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USER_SEQ")
    @Id
    protected long id;
}
```

Validation step in spring boot does not pass. Hibernate throws:

> Schema-validation: missing sequence [public.user_seq]

LiquiBase execute this query:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.user_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1
Sequence user_seq created
```

When I change `ddl-auto` to update, hibernate execute this query:
`create sequence public.user_seq start 1 increment 50`
And JDBC throws exception: `Sequence "user_seq" already exists; SQL statement:`.

**How to correctly create sequence in LiquiBase?**

--
@Edit1 - I Try to use lowercase in entity: USER_SEQ -> user_seq - does not help

Comment: Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41801965/spring-liquibase-recover-when-application-is-crashed/41802213#41802213) and check that your change has been successful.

Comment: `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb` I have whole db in memory so create table starts every time when spring boot starts, changeset is correctly executed. Look at my question(higher) I wrote that LiquiBase execute this SQL: `CREATE SEQUENCE public.user_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1`

Answer (score 2):

I'm using spring boot

Here's my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:liquibase-changeLog.xml
```

Here's my entity

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USER_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "USER_SEQ", sequenceName = "USER_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;

    private String name;
```

Here's my change set

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext
   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd
   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

    <changeSet author="EssexBoy" id="101">

        <createSequence schemaName="public" startValue="1" incrementBy="1" ordered="true" sequenceName="user_seq"/>

        <createTable tableName="user" schemaName="public">
            <column name="id" type="bigint">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)"/>
        </createTable>

    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Here's my test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class LiquibaseExampleApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        repository.save(makeUser("EssexBoy"));
        repository.save(makeUser("EssexDad"));
        repository.save(makeUser("EssexMum"));
        repository.save(makeUser("EssexBaby"));

        repository.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private User makeUser(String name) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);
        return user;
    }
}
```

Output is

```
User{id=1, name='EssexBoy'}
User{id=2, name='EssexDad'}
User{id=3, name='EssexMum'}
User{id=4, name='EssexBaby'}
```

Comment: If u switch `ddl-auto` from none to validate it still works?

Comment: @dramcio yes because validate is just a check, no database creation will take place.

Comment: I have similar code, but when I change to validate, spring does not start