# Is there a configuration for removing LiquiBase DATABASE CHANGELOGLOCK automatically after a certain time or on app restart?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase

We have SpringBoot 2 driven HA java application in which we use PostgreSQL underneath.

For certain reasons like unexpected crashes or Exceptions, Liquibase ends up with a stale DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK which was never released.

This results in subsequent deployments of the app failing with app waiting for the change lock and then exiting as follows:

```
   2020-03-04T11:10:31.78+0200 SELECT LOCKED FROM public.databasechangeloglock WHERE ID=1
   2020-03-04T11:10:31.78+0200 Waiting for changelog lock....
   2020-03-04T11:10:32.87+0200 SELECT LOCKED FROM public.databasechangeloglock WHERE ID=1
   2020-03-04T11:10:32.87+0200 Waiting for changelog lock....
   2020-03-04T11:10:41.78+0200 SELECT LOCKED FROM public.databasechangeloglock WHERE ID=1
   2020-03-04T11:10:41.78+0200 Waiting for changelog lock....
   2020-03-04T11:10:42.87+0200 SELECT LOCKED FROM public.databasechangeloglock WHERE ID=1
   2020-03-04T11:10:42.87+0200 Waiting for changelog lock....
   2020-03-04T11:10:51.79+0200 SELECT LOCKED FROM public.databasechangeloglock WHERE ID=1
   2020-03-04T11:10:51.79+0200 Waiting for changelog lock....
   2020-03-04T11:10:52.88+0200 SELECT LOCKED FROM public.databasechangeloglock WHERE ID=1
   2020-03-04T11:10:52.88+0200 Waiting for changelog lock....
   2020-03-04T11:10:54.00+0200 ERR 2020-03-04 09:10:54.010 UTC
   2020-03-04T11:10:55.88+0200 [HEALTH/0] ERR Failed to make TCP connection to port 8080: connection refused
   2020-03-04T11:10:55.88+0200 [CELL/0] ERR Failed after 1m0.626s: readiness health check never passed.
   2020-03-04T11:10:55.89+0200 [CELL/SSHD/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2020-03-04T11:10:55.89+0200 info    [native] Initiating shutdown sequence for Java agent
   2020-03-04T11:10:55.89+0200 info    [] Connection Status (120 times 300s)      : 0909
```

Is there a configuration for removing Liquibase DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK automatically after a certain time or removing it on application start if it is older than let's say 5 mins or a predefined time period.
Or can this be done programatically at App Start before Postgres starts looking for the change lock.

Comment: Does this actually happen often enough to warrant a "hack"? We're using the same setup and have maybe had this happen once or twice. I'd suggest that you look into what causes these crashes instead

Comment: @ErikKarlstrand Happened only a few times, but it prevents an application from starting in production and that means production downtime till someone gets access and manually tunnels to the db, deletes the lock and then brings back the app. Could be anywhere between a 2 - 4 hours before someone gets the right access and does this manually. So yes, a configuration or a hack would be more apt.

Comment: This is precisely one of the reasons I always run schema migrations manually, and not when the application starts

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But we the service running across 40 - 50 instances, cant change all of them manually.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Found an approach to achieve this and posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was able to achieve this via the following approach:

We initialise LiquiBase using a SpringLiquibase bean.

Within this bean, before the Liquibase instance is constructed, I called a method which uses Statements to query the database for a lock, and if there are any locks older than 5 minutes, we delete them.

```
 @Bean
 public SpringLiquibase liquibase(DataSource dataSource) {
        // Added a hook to check for locks before LiquiBase initialises.
        removeDBLock(dataSource);
        //
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setChangeLog(Constants.DDL_XML);
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return liquibase;
    }



 private void removeDBLock(DataSource dataSource) {
   
    //Timestamp, currently set to 5 mins or older.

    final Timestamp lastDBLockTime = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() - (5 * 60 * 1000));
    
    final String query = format("DELETE FROM DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK WHERE LOCKED=true AND LOCKGRANTED<'%s'", lastDBLockTime.toString());
    

    try (Statement stmt = dataSource.getConnection().createStatement()) {

        int updateCount = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        if(updateCount>0){
            log.error("Locks Removed Count: {} .",updateCount);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Error! Remove Change Lock threw and Exception. ",e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this in non spring boot project?

Answer (score 2):

The default lock implementation provided by Liquibase uses a database table called 'DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK'. Once a process that has acquired the lock is unexpectedly terminated, the only way to recover is to manually release that lock (using the Liquibase CLI or using a SQL statement). Please take a look at this Liquibase extension, which replaces the StandardLockService, by using database locks: https://github.com/blagerweij/liquibase-sessionlock

This extension uses MySQL or Postgres user lock statements, which are automatically released when the database connection is closed (e.g. when the container is stopped unexpectedly). The only thing required to use the extension is to add a dependency to the library. Liquibase will automatically detect the improved LockService.

I'm not the author of the library, but I stumbled upon the library when I was searching for a solution. I helped the author by releasing the library to Maven central. Currently supports MySQL and PostgreSQL, but should be fairly easy to support other RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks for this approach, If you look at the solution I went with, I am also doing something similar but by using a simple check on the changelog lock for stale db locks.

Comment: True, and although your solution works with all database, using a lock function has some advantages: It requires less code (simply add a dependency), but more importantly: there is less risk of running into a race condition: if the schema update runs for more than 5 minutes, removing the lock prematurely might corrupt your database. In our case, we were getting stale locks because Kubernetes decided to kill the container when the liquibase updates took a long time.